# WSDLPull using complex type inputs

Tags: c++, wsdlpull

I'm trying to call a web service method using wsdlpull and it is pretty simple until I get to one service method that accepts a parameter that is an array of complextypes, in this case it takes 1 parameter that is an unbounded number of types containing 2 members - an array of name/value pairs.

```
<s:complexType name="SendDetails">
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Detail" type="tns:Detail"/>
  </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>

<s:complexType name="Detail">
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Value" type="s:string"/>
  </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

and I have no clue how to go about setting these as parameters to wsdlpull.

Does anyone have example code or a snippet to get me started before I rewrite using a different tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `WsdlInvoker` doesn't have support for this (yet?). [`setValue`](http://wsdlpull.sourceforge.net/docs/WsdlInvoker_8cpp-source.html#l00915) calls [`setInputValue`](http://wsdlpull.sourceforge.net/docs/WsdlInvoker_8cpp-source.html#l00788) which in turn calls [`validate`](http://wsdlpull.sourceforge.net/docs/SchemaValidator_8cpp-source.html#l00491), but this method stops processing when a complex type is detected:

```
const XSDType * pType = sParser_->getType(typeId);
if (pType && !pType->isSimple()){
   return 0;
}
```

The only complex type that seems to be supported is one that contains a simple content model.

This said, I think [gSOAP2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gsoap2/) and [Microsoft Windows Web Services API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are better native alternatives.

Comment: FYI WWS was the better tool. Interacted with WCF Soap service perfectly.